# Get data from local xampp mysql-database

Tags: c#, mysql, relational-database, win-universal-app, uwp

Im am trying to connect a local mysql database which runs on xampp with a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) Application. I couldn't find any examples or tutorials on how to archieve this. In one article i have read that this isn't even possible and only sqlite is supported. Is this true?

I have to do a work for school and one criteria is, that it must have a relational database and another is to support multi-user functionality.

I dont know if it is not possible or am I just to blind to find Informations? Sometimes it seems really hard to get to informations to windows app development.

Did someone make experiences with connecting relational databases to UWP-Apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UWP app can connect to any server based database behind a web service. Per my experience, Windows Store app can directly connect to MySQL. Check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-rt.html). I didn't have a chance to try it on win 10 UWP.

Sqlite is the database if you want to deploy a database to the device along with your UWP app.